# Multiple tickets without seating not working

Tags: google-schemas

I want to send out an email with a schema that defines two tickets.
The documentation states:

> If you want to have one ticket (i.e. barcode) per individual and have
>   names for each individual on the ticket, create multiple
>   EventReservations (one per individual) with numSeats set to 1. The
>   example below shows what this looks like.

Sadly this doesn't work like that. If I use this schema (no seating, numSeats set to "1"):

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
[
  {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "EventReservation",
    "reservationNumber": "E123456789",
    "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/Confirmed",
    "underName": {
      "@type": "Person",
      "name": "John Smith"
    },
    "reservationFor": {
      "@type": "Event",
      "name": "Foo Fighters Concert",
      "startDate": "2017-03-06T19:30:00-08:00",
      "location": {
        "@type": "Place",
        "name": "AT&T Park",
        "address": {
          "@type": "PostalAddress",
          "streetAddress": "24 Willie Mays Plaza",
          "addressLocality": "San Francisco",
          "addressRegion": "CA",
          "postalCode": "94107",
          "addressCountry": "US"
        }
      }
    },
    "numSeats": "1",
    "ticketToken": "qrCode:AB34",
    "ticketNumber": "abc123",
    "ticketDownloadUrl": "http://..../ticket.pdf",
    "ticketPrintUrl": "http://..../ticket.pdf"
  },
  {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "EventReservation",
    "reservationNumber": "E123456789",
    "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/Confirmed",
    "underName": {
      "@type": "Person",
      "name": "Eva Green"
    },
    "reservationFor": {
      "@type": "Event",
      "name": "Foo Fighters Concert",
      "startDate": "2017-03-06T19:30:00-08:00",
      "location": {
        "@type": "Place",
        "name": "AT&T Park",
        "address": {
          "@type": "PostalAddress",
          "streetAddress": "24 Willie Mays Plaza",
          "addressLocality": "San Francisco",
          "addressRegion": "CA",
          "postalCode": "94107",
          "addressCountry": "US"
        }
      }
    },
    "numSeats": "1",
    "ticketToken": "qrCode:AB34",
    "ticketNumber": "abc456",
    "ticketDownloadUrl": "http://..../ticket.pdf",
    "ticketPrintUrl": "http://..../ticket.pdf"
  }
]
</script>
```

This will result in a mail in inbox that states that this reservation only contains one Ticket.
The only way to get inbox to state that the reservation contains two tickets is by adding a venueSeat. 
E.g.:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
[
  {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "EventReservation",
    "reservationNumber": "E123456789",
    "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/Confirmed",
    "underName": {
      "@type": "Person",
      "name": "John Smith"
    },
    "reservationFor": {
      "@type": "Event",
      "name": "Foo Fighters Concert",
      "startDate": "2017-03-06T19:30:00-08:00",
      "location": {
        "@type": "Place",
        "name": "AT&T Park",
        "address": {
          "@type": "PostalAddress",
          "streetAddress": "24 Willie Mays Plaza",
          "addressLocality": "San Francisco",
          "addressRegion": "CA",
          "postalCode": "94107",
          "addressCountry": "US"
        }
      }
    },
    "numSeats": "1",
    "venueSeat": "12",
    "ticketToken": "qrCode:AB34",
    "ticketNumber": "abc123",
    "ticketDownloadUrl": "http://..../ticket.pdf",
    "ticketPrintUrl": "http://..../ticket.pdf"
  },
  {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "EventReservation",
    "reservationNumber": "E123456789",
    "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/Confirmed",
    "underName": {
      "@type": "Person",
      "name": "Eva Green"
    },
    "reservationFor": {
      "@type": "Event",
      "name": "Foo Fighters Concert",
      "startDate": "2017-03-06T19:30:00-08:00",
      "location": {
        "@type": "Place",
        "name": "AT&T Park",
        "address": {
          "@type": "PostalAddress",
          "streetAddress": "24 Willie Mays Plaza",
          "addressLocality": "San Francisco",
          "addressRegion": "CA",
          "postalCode": "94107",
          "addressCountry": "US"
        }
      }
    },
    "numSeats": "1",
    "venueSeat": "13",
    "ticketToken": "qrCode:AB34",
    "ticketNumber": "abc456",
    "ticketDownloadUrl": "http://..../ticket.pdf",
    "ticketPrintUrl": "http://..../ticket.pdf"
 }
]
</script>
```

With this script the mail in inbox will correctly state that the reservation contains two tickets and will additionally print the two seats.
But in my case we do not have reserved seats, so I can't add this parameter.

Any ideas how to solve this or any plans from google to fix this?

Bonus question: 
I wasn't able to actually see the ticket. Neither the QR-Code, nor a download link to the PDF. Any ideas why that is?

Comment: This seems like a support question for Google rather than a programming question.  I sympathize, since I know it would be hard to get an answer from them, but I'm not sure this is the right place to get an answer.

Comment: The support page of the schema documentation states to post here and google engineers would watch the google-schemas tag.
Let's see...

Comment: well, in that case...

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [documentaiton](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/event-reservation#multiple_tickets) "There are two options to do multiple tickets":

*The first is change **numSeats**. This means a **single reservation** will represent tickets for **numSeats** number of individuals.* This will be the option you want since you don't have reserved seating.

I used the following schema:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "EventReservation",
  "reservationNumber": "ABCD12345",
  "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/Confirmed",
  "underName": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "John Smith"
  },
  "reservationFor": {
    "@type": "MusicEvent",
    "name": "Foo Fighters Concert",
    "url": "http://foofighterstour.com/SFO",
    "performer": {
      "@type": "Person",
      "name": "The Foo Fighters",
      "image": "http://www.amprocktv.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/foo-fighters-1-680x383.jpg"
    },
    "startDate": "2015-05-24T12:00:00-08:00",
    "endDate": "2015-05-24T16:00:00-08:00",
    "doorTime": "2015-05-24T11:00:00-08:00",
    "location": {
      "@type": "Place",
      "name": "AT&T Park",
      "address": {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        "streetAddress": "AT&T Park",
        "addressLocality": "San Francisco",
        "addressRegion": "CA",
        "postalCode": "94107",
        "addressCountry": "US"
      }
    }
  },
     "ticketDownloadUrl": "http://www.example.pdf",
    "ticketPrintUrl": "http://www.example.pdf",
    "modifyreservationurl": "http://www.example.pdf",
  "ticketToken": "qrCode:AB34",
  "ticketNumber": "abc12345",
  "numSeats": "2"
}
</script>
```

I was able to generate 2 tickets in Inbox, create 2 Google Now cards, generate an action button (modify reservation) in Gmail and Inbox. The modify reservation action button leads to the ticket. Note I tried just using the "URL" property, to generate the "View Ticket" action button, but noticed it disappears. I was also able to generate the QRcode as well, however, the QRcode appeared to be broken on the second Now card.

[image: Email in Google Inbox]

[image: Email in Gmail]

[image: Now Card 1]

[image: Now Card 2]

***Update** - the previous card screenshots were from my iphone using [Google](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google/id284815942?mt=8&utm_content=bufferee152&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer), the cards appear different on a Android device. One of the ticket properties (ticketdownloadurl / ticketprinturl) appeared when using an Android device:

[image]

[image]